# Generic class from type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is there a way to create a generic class from type parameter.

I have something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Type TypeOfAnotherClass { get; set; }
}

public class OneMoreClass
{
}

public class GenericClass<T>
    where T : class
{
    public void DoNothing() {}
}

public class GenericClass
{
    public static GenericClass<T> GetInstance<T>(T ignored)
        where T : class
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}
```

What I want is to create a GenericClass from a Type. Ex:

```
var SC = new SomeClass();
SC.TypeOfAnotherClass = typeof(OneMoreClass);
var generic = GenericClass.GetInstance(SC.TypeOfAnotherClass);

Assert.AreEqual(typeof(GenericClass<OneMoreClass>), generic.GetType());
```

Here I expect to get instance of `GenericClass<OneMoreClass>` but I get `GenericClass<Type>`

I also tried using instance of that type. Ex:

```
var generic = GenericClass.GetInstance(Activator.CreateInstance(SC.TypeOfAnotherClass));
```

This time I get `GenericClass<object>`

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know the type you actually want (`OneMoreClass`) at build time, then you should just use it:

```
var generic = GenericClass.GetInstance<OneMoreClass>();
```

But I am assuming you don't know it at build time, and have to get the `type` at runtime.
You can do it with reflection, but it isn't pretty, and is slow:

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
    }
}
```

Since you don't know the resulting type at build time, you can't return anything but `object` (or `dynamic`) from the method.

---

Here is how much slower (for 100,000 creates)

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
    }

    public static GenericClass<T> GetInstance<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}

    [Test]
    public void CanMakeGenericViaReflection_ButItsSlow()
    {
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        var SC = new SomeClass();
        SC.TypeOfAnotherClass = typeof(OneMoreClass);

        timer.Start();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
        {
            GenericClass.GetInstance(SC.TypeOfAnotherClass);
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("With Reflection: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");

        timer.Restart();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
        {
            GenericClass.GetInstance<OneMoreClass>();
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Without Reflection: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.");
    }
```

Results:

```
With Reflection: 243ms.
Without Reflection: 2ms.
```

So a little over 100x slower.

The real thing to note about generics is that the `<T>`s in generics are resolved at *build-time* by the C# compiler, and the real class names are inserted. When you have to defer that until run-time, you end up paying the performance price.

Comment: @Gabe - I added more to my answer to show the performance hit of using reflection.

Comment: So "slow" means "it takes 2 microseconds". That's pretty fast if you are only doing it a few thousand times per second, but too slow if you need to do it millions of times.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted. About returned `object`: I made an `interface` of `GenericClass` an converting object to it. And performance will not effect me because only one instance of one type is created at a time. So really thanks, I was looking for this solution for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking here. If I understood you properly, this is what you are looking for:

```
public class GenericClass
{
    public static GenericClass<T> GetInstance<T>(T ignored)
        where T : class
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }

    public static GenericClass<T> GetInstance<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}
```

Th usage:

```
  var generic1 = GenericClass.GetInstance<OneMoreClass>();
  var generic2 = GenericClass.GetInstance(new OneMoreClass());
```

Assertions:

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(GenericClass<OneMoreClass>), generic1.GetType());
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(GenericClass<OneMoreClass>), generic2.GetType());
```